# How does determining subclass through hasattr trigger a db query in django's orm?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

For example, I am using multi-table inheritance for a class Node with sub-classes ConceptNode and DerivedNode.  To determine the type of Node I am dealing with and distribute a function call down to the appropriate subclass, I often have to call hasattr like this:

```
test_node = Node.objects.all()[0]

if hasattr( test_node, "conceptnode"):
    test_node.conceptnode.myFunction()
elif hasattr( test_node, "derivednode"):
    test_node.derivednode.myFunction()
else:
   raise Exception("Not a valid type.")
```

I've noticed that this results in multiple db queries, which add up to really slow down some functions I've written.

I've tried another approach using try...catch which does not decrease the number of queries.

```
test_node = Node.objects.all()[0]

try:
    test_node.conceptnode.myFunction()
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    test_node.derivednode.myFunction()
```

My main question is: how does django determine what queries to execute here?  I don't see how hasattr is getting translated into a db query.

Also, if anyone can suggest a more efficient way to handle this (esp. from a query count perspective), that would be great too!

EDIT: To dump the sqlite queries performed I did the following:

```
from django.db import connection
from django import db
db.reset_queries()
hasattr(nds[0],'conceptnode')
hasattr(nds[0],'derivednode')
connection.queries
```

And I got the following results:

```
{'sql': u'SELECT "nodes_node"."id", "nodes_node"."name", "nodes_node"."description", "nodes_node"."node_tree_id", "nodes_node"."unique_name", "nodes_node"."last_updated_timestamp", "nodes_node"."order", "nodes_node"."data_json", "nodes_node"."data_json_synchronized" FROM "nodes_node" LIMIT 1',  'time': '0.001'}
{'sql': u'SELECT "nodes_node"."id", "nodes_node"."name", "nodes_node"."description", "nodes_node"."node_tree_id", "nodes_node"."unique_name", "nodes_node"."last_updated_timestamp", "nodes_node"."order", "nodes_node"."data_json", "nodes_node"."data_json_synchronized", "nodes_conceptnode"."node_ptr_id", "nodes_conceptnode"."node_parent_id" FROM "nodes_conceptnode" INNER JOIN "nodes_node" ON ("nodes_conceptnode"."node_ptr_id" = "nodes_node"."id") WHERE "nodes_conceptnode"."node_ptr_id" = 1 ',  'time': '0.000'}
{'sql': u'SELECT "nodes_node"."id", "nodes_node"."name", "nodes_node"."description", "nodes_node"."node_tree_id", "nodes_node"."unique_name", "nodes_node"."last_updated_timestamp", "nodes_node"."order", "nodes_node"."data_json", "nodes_node"."data_json_synchronized" FROM "nodes_node" LIMIT 1',  'time': '0.001'}
{'sql': u'SELECT "nodes_node"."id", "nodes_node"."name", "nodes_node"."description", "nodes_node"."node_tree_id", "nodes_node"."unique_name", "nodes_node"."last_updated_timestamp", "nodes_node"."order", "nodes_node"."data_json", "nodes_node"."data_json_synchronized", "nodes_derivednode"."node_ptr_id", "nodes_derivednode"."node_source_id", "nodes_derivednode"."node_target_id" FROM "nodes_derivednode" INNER JOIN "nodes_node" ON ("nodes_derivednode"."node_ptr_id" = "nodes_node"."id") WHERE "nodes_derivednode"."node_ptr_id" = 1 ',  'time': '0.000'}
```

The first and third of these are fetching the original node object.

Comment: @ColeMaclean - I added them to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two instances of the simple node lookup (the `LIMIT 1` query) because you are accessing a queryset as a list multiple times.

```
nodes = Node.objects.all()
nodes[0]
nodes[0]
```

triggers two queries, whereas:

```
node = Node.objects.all()[0]
node
node
```

triggers one. This can seem a bit strange at first, but the key is to remember that `Node.objects.all()` is not evaluated (no queries are made) until you access it.

As for why a single object lookup runs two queries, you are using [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance). If you just have this in your model:

```
class Node(models.Model):
    pass

class ConceptNode(Node):
    pass
```

Django will create two tables, with `ConceptNode` rows having a parent `Node`.

What you're probably looking for is an [abstract base class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes), which will allow you to share methods and properties between multiple classes while just using a single table for each. Just add `abstract = True` to the parent class meta:

```
class Node(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Finally, note that both of these queries should take almost no time, so I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Comment: Thanks Cole.  I am pretty sure Django is looking in the table "nodes_attribute" (where attribute could be conceptnode or derivednode) and looking to see if an entry exists where the foreign key "node_ptr_id" is the same as the current node id.  I am guessing all these names are automatically created by Django and are used in the orm code, but I wanted to make sure my mental model of how this works is accurate.

Comment: Check the updated answer, it should cover this now. The Django docs are your friends, although there's so much in there it's hard to know where to start.